# React Navigation Page doesnt get unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

This is my `AppNavigator.js` :

```
const unChosenDeviceAppStack = createStackNavigator({
  DevicesList: {
      screen: DevicesList,
     },
},
);

const chosenDeviceAppStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreenPage: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
  },
);
```

and there is a `Loading` file which decides which page to navigate at launch, (Consider it navigates to HomescreenPage).

Each Device in `DeviceLists` has a unique `HomeScreenPage`

**The Problem:**

app navigates to `HomescreenPage` at launch, then i navigate to DeviceLists and again i choose a Device there and it navigates again to `HomescreenPage`. the point is `HomescreenPage` was not unmounted!!! it renders the same page it was showing at launch.

i expected when i navigate from `HomescreenPage` to `DeviceLists`(which is in another `stack`) , first page gets unmounted but that not happening!

can someone tell me what is exactly happening?
and how to unmount that page and re-render it completely when navigating again to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike classic reactjs lifecycle for components, *react navigation* with *react native* works in a different way. When you navigate from screen A to screen B, screen A doesn't get unmounted. You can get a full explanation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html

How to solve this problem?

You can simply listen to *didFocus/willFocus* events on a specific screen and trigger some kind of state changes (which will makes your screen to re-render).

```js
// add listener here
componentDidMount () {
  this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
    // do some magic here and change state
  }
}

// don't forget to remove the listener
componentWillUnmount () {
  this.focusListener.remove() 
}
```